# Running Macros from Toolbar/Running one macro from another

Tags: vba, publisher, ms-publisher

I am trying to develop a macro for a publisher document. This macro will, when run, show a pop-up allowing the user to select one of three types of clients, and add different bullet points to a text box depending on which option was selected. I'm having two different problems which I suspect are coming from the same source. Problem number one is that I can't get the button on my User Form to run a different macro when the button is clicked. Problem two is that I've added my macros to one of the toolbars, and nothing happens when I click on them. In both cases, it's simply not running the macro. What am I doing wrong?

UserForm1

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.Run ("ShapeTest")
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
With ListBox1
.AddItem ("Federal")
.AddItem ("State")
.AddItem ("Local")
End With
End Sub
```

ThisDocument

```
Private Sub GenerateStatement()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub

Private Sub ShapeTest()
MsgBox ("Hello!")
Application.ActiveDocument.Pages(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.InsertAfter`enter code here`(Chr(13) & "My Text")
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `Application.Run("ShapeTest")` rather than simply `ShapeTest`?

I don't have enough information to be 100% sure, but the following should work: To make `ShapeTest` callable from the userform you do two things:

1) Move it from `ThisDocument` to a general code module (first `Insert/Module` in the editor).

2) Eliminate the word `Private` in front of `Sub ShapeTest()`-- you don't *want* this to be a private sub since you want code outside of the module to be able to use it.

On edit: Alternatively -- you could keep `ShapeTest()` where it is in `ThisDocument`, get rid of the `Private` qualifier and in the userform code refer to `ShapeTest` as `ThisDocument.ShapeTest`. I prefer using the first method since I tend to like to keep as much code as possible in general code modules (reserving things like `ThisDocument` for event handlers) but OTOH my VBA experience is mostly Excel with a smattering of Word and there might be reasons to keep the code in `ThisDocument` in Publisher. I don't know Publisher, but a problem that I have run into in Word at times is I have sometimes accidentally put code in the `Normal` template that I wanted to go in the document's project. If something similar is possible in Publisher you should double check where your code is living.